# Template for a family of functions designed to copy/convert objects

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I would like to write a family of copy/conversion functions named `copy` that copies from object A to object B. For instance

```
void f(const A& a) {
  B b = copy<B>(a);
  ...
}
```

For instance A could be a `std::array<double, 5>` and B could be a `std::vector<double>`.

Is it possible to do such a thing and define for once the specialization that converts from any `std::array<T, n>` to `std::vector<T>`? In another file I would also like to define for once the specialization that converts from any `std::array<T, n>` to `CudaVector<T>`. In another file I would like to define the conversion from `SparseMatrix<T>` to `DenseMatrix<T>`, etc...

If you don't find any solution for that, do you think of any way to do something similar, as long as I still have value semantics (I don't want to define `copy(const A& input, B& output)`).

Comment: You can always use `std::copy`.

Comment: @Rakete1111. I want value semantics, meaning that the new objects should be returned by the function. I also want this function to work with objects that don't have iterators.

Comment: If the objects don't have iterators (or pointers), then it might not be possible to write a general copy function: how would you know to call mem func `toArray()` from A to get a B? You'll need to restrict what types of A are acceptable, and if they support iterators, you can just make a wrapper around `std::copy`.

Comment: @Rakete1111. I don't want to write a general function. I want to template/overload-specialize it for every couple A<T>, B<T>

Comment: @InsideLoop: So... do that. If you want to write a specialized version of `copy` for every possible A and B type, what is stopping you?

Comment: @Nicol: I know how to write a function that can be called: `B b = copy<B, A>(a)` but I don't know how to call it `B b = copy<B>(a)`. I just don't want to retype the type of a as it is given by a.

Comment: You shouldn't need to, there's [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) for function templates in C++11. `A` can be deduced from the first function parameter, so you can leave it out.

Comment: @The Vee: Thanks. I did not knew that. I thought that it was either full deduction or nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible thanks to [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). The from-type can be deduced from the argument, the return type needs to be explicitly stated.

There's one other problem and that is that if the plan is to have specializations for converting various containers to various other containers, you would need partial function specializations, which are not allowed. But an usual trick can work around that using partial specializations of classes instead.

For example, this works as a generic template and its specialization for copy-converting a `std::array` to a `std::vector` of the same element type:

```
template<typename B, typename A>
struct copier {
  //static B copy(const A&); // Is there a generic fall-back algorithm? Probably not.
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct copier<std::vector<int>, std::array<T, N>> {
  static std::vector<int> copy(const std::array<T, N>& a) {
    std::vector<int> b{};
    std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b));
    return b;
  }
};

template<typename B, typename A>
B mcopy(const A& a) {
  return copier<B, A>::copy(a);
}
```

Then you can call this using

```
std::array<int, 3> a{1, 2, 3};
using B = std::vector<int>;
B b = mcopy<B>(a);
```

which looks just like the line from your question.

Note that `copy` is not a very good name for this function. [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) would kick in and find `std::copy` as long as the type `A` is in namespace `std`, which might lead to very strange error messages.